# iPhone will not vibrate while displaying camera view

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, vibration

I can programmatically make the phone vibrate, but for some reason it stops working while a live camera view is being displayed. Could it be that the uiimagepicker is intercepting audio playback? Once I dismiss the live view vibrating resumes.

Comment: its probably to prevent the vibrations from moving the phone and creating a blurry image?

Comment: I don't think this is the case, but I didn't think about how vibration would affect the video clarity. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that vibrates while showing a camera view, but I use [AVFF](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188), not `UIImagePickerController`. So it may be something in `UIImagePickerController` or it might be something unrelated in your code.